# How to load Wicket CSS and Icon resources correctly?

Tags: java, css, wicket, sprite-sheet

I am looking for a best practice way on how to load a CSS file and an icon spritesheet with Wicket (version 9).
I have several Java projects and the CSS and icon spritesheet is part contained in `my-resources.jar`.

Previously, the folder structure was as follows:

- `META-INF/resources/css/my.css`
- `META-INF/resources/icons/spritesheet.png`

The CSS was included in my page using:

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
  super.renderHead(response);
  response.render(CssHeaderItem.forReference(new MyCssResourceReference()));
}
```

where the Reference class is:

```
package com.example.myapp.resources;

public class MyCssResourceReferenceextends CssResourceReference {
  public MyCssResourceReference()
  {
    // number of .. corresponds to package this class is located in
    super(MyCssResourceReference.class, "../../../../META-INF/resources/css/my.css");
  }
}
```

Inside the CSS, the spritesheet is referenced like this:

```
.button {
  background: url(../icons/spritesheet.png);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.button-close {
  background-position: -40px 0px;
}
```

This had the advantage that the icon spritesheet was found implicitly without the need to mount it as a resource for it. But it also has several drawbacks:

- need to adjust the number of `..` used in the path if the class `MyCssResourceReference` is moved in a different package
- "magic" that the icon spritesheet is being found without explicit mention in any Wicket code
- undertow had trouble serving contents in the META-INF directory (https://issues.redhat.com/browse/UNDERTOW-2186) which lead to problems if the app was run in a JBOSS server

Therefore, I now want to restructure how the CSS and icon spritehseet resources are delivered.
What's the preferred way of doing this in Wicket?

I want to keep a separate JAR file for my resources, but I'm free to move the resources to a different folder/package. Does it make sense to use Wicket's shared resource mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> need to adjust the number of .. used in the path if the class MyCssResourceReference is moved in a different package

super(MyCssResourceReference.class, "../../../../META-INF/resources/css/my.css");

Since you want to point to the `root` you can just do:

```
 super(MyCssResourceReference.class, "/META-INF/resources/css/my.css");
```

Wicket uses `java.lang.Class#getResource()` to load the classpath resources.

> "magic" that the icon spritesheet is being found without explicit mention in any Wicket code

I wouldn't say it is magic! This is how relative paths work! The browser calculates the absolute path and makes an HTTP request that Wicket processes without issues.

> undertow had trouble serving contents in the META-INF directory

You can use `/static` instead of `/META-INF`! Or any other custom name you like

Comment: Using an absolute path does not work, because the `BasicResourceReferenceMapper` will not pick up the initial `/` when creating the name for the resource and therefore the resource will not be found in the ResourceReferenceRegistry...

Comment: Using a different name for the static folder does work, but it's still weird to me that the icons will be picked up with an URL like `http://server/app/wicket/resource/com.example.myapp.resources.MyCssResourceReference/::/::/::/::/static/icons/spritesheet.png`, because the ResourceReference of that URL should *only* serve the `my.css`, not any resource on the classpath...

Comment: The ResourceReference is used to construct the absolute path to the CSS file. But the image paths inside it use relative paths which the browser resolves to absolute paths. E.g. `https://host/some/absolute/path.css` and `https://host/some/absolute/path.png`. The `::` are special in Wicket to go to the parent folder. I'll have to debug BasicResourceReferenceMapper to see why the leading `/` is ignored.